# When building an app with Xcode, how do I build it from scratch again?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

I want to do a from-scratch build of my app. The only way I've figured out how to do it is with deleting it from the iPhone/iPad itself, but this seems rather work-aroundy. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean the project( Shift + command + k) or reset the simulator settings.

Answer (score 0):

In organizer, click on projects->your project, and delete the derived data. Alternatively, you can clean the project (shift+command+k). This gets rid of the built product, and next time you build or run it, Xcode recompiles it.